# Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Division'

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a pricing function that takes a `usd` price and a `eur` price and does some calculations. However I am getting the following error when trying to ran it:

> Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Division'.
> At line:11 char:5

**Code:**

```bsh
function Get-Pricing($USD, $EUR) {
    [hashtable]$Return = @{}

    $USDGBP = [math]::Round((Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD").rates.GBP,2)
    $EURGBP = [math]::Round((Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=EUR").rates.GBP,2)

    $USDEx = ($USD * $USDGBP)
    $EUREx = ($EUR * $EURGBP)

    $ReturnedPrice = ((( $EUREx + 0.25 ) * 0.32 ) + $EUREx )
    $PriceIndex = (((( $USDEx / $ReturnedPrice ) * 0.5 ) + (( $EUREx / $ReturnedPrice ) * 1.5 ) + 1 ) / 3)

    $PriceCM = (( $ReturnedPrice / $EUREx ) * $PriceIndex )

    $Return.PriceIndex = $PriceIndex
    $Return.PriceCM = $PriceCM

    Return $Return
}

[float]$a = 23.83
[float]$b = 16.11

Write-Host $a  -ForegroundColor Red
Write-Host $b  -ForegroundColor Red

$Pricing = Get-Pricing($a, $b)

Write-Host "A: "$Pricing.PriceIndex -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-Host "B: "$Pricing.PriceCM -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

Comment: `Get-Pricing($a, $b)` -> `Get-Pricing -a $a -b $b`

Comment: That worked thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell's command invocation syntax is slightly different from other languages with C-style syntax, you have to bind parameter arguments either by name:

```
Get-Pricing -USD $a -EUR $b
```

or by position:

```
Get-Pricing $a $b
```

But when you do this:

```
Get-Pricing ($a, $b)
            \______/
               |
      # PowerShell just sees a single argument here
```

... you're effectively passing a 2-item array to the `$USD` parameter, and nothing to the `$EUR` parameter.

---

If you explicitly type your parameters, the runtime binder will be able to tell you what is wrong:

```bsh
PS C:\> function Get-Pricing([float]$USD, [float]$EUR) {
>>   # ...
>> }
PS C:\> Get-Pricing($a,$b)
Get-Pricing : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'USD'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type
"System.Object[]" to type "System.Single".
At line:1 char:12
+ Get-Pricing($a,$b)
+            ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Pricing], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Get-Pricing
```